# SQL using stored procedure and cursor

Tags: sql

I have a sql database table as follows.

```
SeqID DevicesID EmployeeID Type Time
1     2         624        0    2014-07-01 09:00:08.000
2     2         624        1    2014-07-02 01:00:18.000
3     2         624        0    2014-07-02 08:55:11.000
4     2         624        0    2014-07-02 09:00:12.000
5     2         624        1    2014-07-02 17:00:14.000
```

I want to take the record is as follows:

```
SeqID DevicesID EmployeeID Type Time
1     2         624        0    2014-07-01 09:00:08.000
2     2         624        1    2014-07-02 01:00:18.000
3     2         624        0    2014-07-02 08:55:11.000
5     2         624        1    2014-07-02 17:00:14.000
```

0 = Check In
1 = Check Out

provisions

if there is a clock in on 01-07-2014, 09:00:08 hours he missed, and he clocked 1:00:18 hours on 02-07-2014,

he was on the same clock in hours 08:55:11, 2014-07-02 09:00:12, and 17:00:14 hours clocked on.

If anyone could help me, please.

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SynchronizeCheckInOutBackup]
   @DevicesID AS INTEGER,
   @EmployeeID AS INTEGER,
   @Type AS INTEGER,
   @Time AS DATETIME
   AS
   BEGIN
        DECLARE @SequenceID AS INTEGER
        DECLARE @TempTime AS DATETIME

        IF (@Type = 0)
        BEGIN
             IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CheckInOut WHERE DevicesID = @DevicesID AND 
                EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND Type = @Type)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO CheckInOut(DevicesID, EmployeeID, Type, Time)
                    VALUES (@DevicesID, @EmployeeID, @Type, @Time)
                END
             ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @TempTime = Time FROM CheckInOut 
                    WHERE DevicesID = @DevicesID AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND Type 
                    = @Type

                    IF (@Time < @TempTime) 
                         BEGIN
                              SELECT @SequenceID = SequenceID FROM CheckInOut 
                              WHERE DevicesID = @DevicesID AND EmployeeID = 
                              @EmployeeID AND Type = @Type 

                            UPDATE CheckInOut
                SET Type = @Type, Time = @Time 
                WHERE SequenceID = @SequenceID
            END 
        END
END

IF (@Type = 1)
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CheckInOut WHERE DevicesID = @DevicesID AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND Type = @Type)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO CheckInOut(DevicesID, EmployeeID, Type, Time)
            VALUES (@DevicesID, @EmployeeID, @Type, @Time)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @TempTime = Time FROM CheckInOut 
            WHERE DevicesID = @DevicesID AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND Type = @Type

            IF (@Time > @TempTime) 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SequenceID = SequenceID FROM CheckInOut 
                WHERE DevicesID = @DevicesID AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND Type = @Type 

                UPDATE CheckInOut
                SET Type = @Type, Time = @Time 
                WHERE SequenceID = @SequenceID
            END 
        END
END
```

END

Comment: Interpretation: He wants a query that will account for (and ignore) superfluous "Check In" records (I think)

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  What database is this for?

Comment: call center software sucks to report on, no? COnfirm for us...all you are going for is to elminate the double login?  Database type would also help

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to produce here but take a look at the DATEDIFF function; It may help in this circumstance. ie: finding differences between two times; if they are in the correct timeframe, add them together.